# Why is $\{f(x)\in F[x]| f(a) = 0\}$ where $a$ is an algebraic element over $F$ a principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If $E$ is an extension field of $F$ and $a \in E\setminus F$ and $a$ is algebraic over $F$, then how can we prove that there exists a $g\in \{f(x)\in F[x]| f(a) = 0\}$ such that $(g) = \{f(x)\in F[x]| f(a) = 0\}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any idea? the first you want to think is if you can guess what is $g$, and then prove it. If you don't have any idea on what will $g$ be you shoud try to make some easy examples and see what happens.

Comment: Comments: 1)  Is this at all specific to [tag:finite-fields]? What was you reason for selecting that tag? 2) You should remember from an earlier course (or earlier parts of this course) that every ideal of $F[x]$ is principal.

Answer (score 2):

Define a ring morphism $\phi: F[x]\rightarrow E$ by "evaluating at $a$", that is:

$$\phi(f) = f(a) $$

Since $a$ is algebraic, this morphism has non trivial kernel, which is then an ideal of $F[x]$. Every ideal in $F[x]$ is principal.

Comment: But wouldn't that only prove $\ker(\phi) \subseteq \{f(x)|f(a)=0\}$?

Comment: No, the kernel of $\phi$ and the subset of polynomials with root $a$ are equal, by the very definition of kernel.

Comment: The proof also shows that the polynomials with root $a$ actually form a *maximal* ideal, because the quotient ring is, by the isomorphy theorem, a subring of $E$, which must be a field because $E$ is.

Comment: @Compacto I know what you mean but not all subrings of a field are fields. Not even if they contain the prime field. Consider $\Bbb{Q}[\pi]\subseteq\Bbb{R}$. A more precise statement is that if $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields and $R$ is an intermediate ring, $K\subseteq R\subseteq L$, then $R$ is a field.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We take $f\neq 0$ with minimal degree and leading coefficient $1$ in the set. Now let $g$ be some polynomial in the set, and divide $g$ by $f$ with remainder : $g=fq+r$, with degree of $r$ less than degree of $f$. But: $g(a)=fq(a)+r(a)=0$ and therefore $r(a)=0$. By minimality of the degree of $f$, $r=0$. So $g=fq$. Therefore $f$ generates the ideal.